# External proxy an Titanium Web Proxy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy

I got proxy on my physical machine and this is not work for me.
Actualy i listen on port 18882 for any ip address and get req/resp.

`_proxyServer = new ProxyServer();
var explicitEndPoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 18882, true);
_proxyServer.AddEndPoint(explicitEndPoint);
_proxyServer.Start();`

I tried this but not work also..

`_proxyServer.UpStreamHttpProxy = new ExternalProxy() { HostName = id, Port = port }`

I use Selenium and if i set chrome options on this, Google Chrome cant open page

How i can setup titanium.web.proxy to use external proxy? So something like this

**Request site -> Titanium.Web.Proxy.Http -> Our own proxy -> Website**